# while loop does not break

Tags: python-3.x, while-loop

Hi guys i m new in python, and I have problem with this program.
When I run this program the if statement does not work.
I am giving `luccy` name to input, but the `if` statement does not process it as it should.

```
enter my boy name
hi
i dont have such a boy hi
enter my boy name
luccy
i dont have such a boy luccy
enter my boy name
```

**Code:**

```
myboys =['luccy']
while True:
    print('enter my boy name name')
    name = input()
    if name in myboys:
    print('haha he is my boy')
    break

else:
 print('i dont have such a boy ' + name)
```

So I edited my program as you fellas said, so now my problem is with the `break` statement.

Comment: The problem is that your definition of myboys is a list. And your input is a string. Change your if statement to` if name in myboys`.

Comment: The indentation in your program as you show it is incorrect. Please edit to show the *actual* code you're using, with correct indentation.

Comment: i tried the changing (if name in myboys and worked.tnx guys .sry for beeing so much noob in python and asking basic questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
myboys = ['luccy']
while True:
    name = input('enter my boy name:')
    if name.strip().lower() in myboys:
        print('haha he is my boy')
        break

    else:
        print('i dont have such a boy ' + name)
```

`name.strip().lower()` will strip the leading blank spaces and lowercase the name.

**HINT:**
You should use set: `myboys = {'luccy'}`